# Syntax assist for method type definition?

Tags: go

Apologies if this is obvious; relatively new to Golang.

I need to pass a function with a pointer receiver as an argument to a method, and to store that function pointer in other structs, etc.

Without a receiver, this is straightforward.  For a function such as...

```
func Sample(ctx *Context, arg int) (err error)
```

...I can create a function type by using the syntax...

```
type SampleFunc func (ctx *Context, arg int) (err error)
```

...but for a function with a receiver such as...

```
func (ctx *Context) Sample(arg int) (err error)
```

...what's the syntax for the type definition?  I tried...

```
type SampleFunc func (ctx *Context) (arg int) (err error)
```

...but that just yields `syntax error: unexpected ( after top level declaration`

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

```
type SampleFunc func (ctx *Context, arg int) (err error)
```

Assign the `Sample` method to a variable of type `SampleFunc` like this:

```
var f SampleFunc = (*Context).Sample
```

The `(*)` part is required for pointer receiver methods. Call it like this:

```
 f(ctx, 1)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/08D0DQK_8P)

Comment: Oh, I see.

Thanks for taking the time; much appreciated.